# What's the best way to detect in which div am i to change the style of a navbar in React?

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I'm making a single page project and i want to add a border bottom color in my navbar when the page is in the div that the navbar takes you using react-scroll. What's the best way to detect in what div am i? My idea was that somehow i can have a state that is the place where the user is in the page and then the matching element in my navbar has a border color to represent where you are.

I tried using Intersection Observer but i't doesn't feel like the best way for it, for example i have divs that are pretty big and some that are small and in a page it can be 3 at the same time and intersection observer.isVisible works really weird.

[image]

For example if i'm in the logo div in the page to add a cool border to the Logo i in my navbar.

[image]

If i'm in the second section add a border to the second section text in my nav.

Using is intersecting the state updates but sometimes it updates to false after i'm way out of the div.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../../App.css";

const Second = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      const entry = entries[0];
      console.log(entry.isVisible);
      setIsVisible(entry.isVisible);
    });
    observer.observe(ref.current);
  }, []);
  return <div id="second" ref={ref}></div>;
};

export default Second;
```

The second div looks like this:
[image]

Even where the react-scroll takes me isIntersecting is equal to false, and using the same but with isVisible is false 24/7.

Comment: Can you post the code, or what you tried ?

Comment: Just added how the size of the divs look and how i was working with intersectionObserver

Answer (score 0):

You can set an id for each div. And change the links of the navbar as `#services`. So that you can detect the location of the window by `window.location`. If that is equal to the nav link you can add a dynamic class to that link. I think this is an easy way to do this without intersectionObserver.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li className={`navlink ${window.location === '/#services' && 'navlink-active'}`}><a href="#services">Services</a></>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```